# How to access json content from external url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm new to jquery and javascript and I've been trying to access the contents of a json file from an external link with no luck. The json file is produced in the link below.

http://api.wmata.com/StationPrediction.svc/json/GetPrediction/A10,A11?api_key=hadtcpbh3w5xjbtyqrzgm88x

I noticed that several examples have a url similar to this "www.samplesite.com/testfile.json"  However, as you can see above, the URL is not like this.  Opening the link in Chrome takes you directly to the json file contents, however opening the file in IE asks you if you want to save the file "A10,A11.json".

All I want to do is be able to display the json file content in HTML.  Can some please show me a brief example.

Thank you

Comment: You are aware that for security reasons, browsers are not allowed to make cross-domain requests?  Are you working on a page for wmata.com or a page for a different site?

You are aware that for security reasons, browsers are not allowed to make cross-domain requests?  Are you working on a page for wmata.com or a page for a different site?


If you have access to the host, use CORS or JSONP.  If you do not, you will need to set up a page on your server that will request the page and then relay it to your javascript.

Comment: That may be true, but there are workarounds available.

Comment: That doesn't matter. This is an API provided by wmata. That means by default cross-origin requests would be allowed by the servers at wmata.

Comment: @Newtt XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.wmata.com/StationPrediction.svc/json/GetPrediction/A10,A11?api_key=hadtcpbh3w5xjbtyqrzgm88x&_=1409862899562. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://stackoverflow.com' is therefore not allowed access.   Did you try it before making that comment, because what you are saying does not appear to be true.

Comment: @DrewFaubion, did you try?. http://i.imgur.com/Ks7qbbF.png

Comment: My code will work. If you want to test it manually, add callback=blah to the URL and see!

Comment: @Newtt, I don't see how showing me that you visited the page is any indication of a successful cross-domain request.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your time and input.  The code evilunix provided worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://api.wmata.com/StationPrediction.svc/json/GetPrediction/A10,A11?api_key=hadtcpbh3w5xjbtyqrzgm88x',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(data){// your code here
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the JSON only if the website having the JSON allows cross origin resource sharing(CORS). Find out if that is available, and if it is then post your code.

Comment: If someone doesnt like the answer, they should tell why instead of down voting without reason, it lets everyone learn.

Comment: Indeed. Somebody downvoted my answer, even though it works... Strange.

Comment: I don't have the power to downvote, but I suspect it is because you are incorrect.  There are other ways to make cross-domain requests than just CORS.

Comment: Please share the link if you find any, I dont mind being wrong, I just need more than "You're wrong"

Comment: I check but coudn't find anythihg.  However the code evilunix provided worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON('http://api.wmata.com/StationPrediction.svc/json/GetPrediction/A10,A11?api_key=hadtcpbh3w5xjbtyqrzgm88x', function(data) {
    //data is the JSON string
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve JSON from servers outside your own domain, you should set up the callback to retrieve so called 'padded' JSON, which is easily done by adding the following to the jQuery .ajax() function:

```
 dataType: 'jsonp'
```